# Creating array with change log data and sending it via email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a script which will periodically collect information about changes to my spreadsheet and send it via e-mail (every 4 hours, for example).

With the help of other tutorials I was able to create such a script:

```
function grabData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd-MM-yyyy')+' at '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'hh:mm');;
  var dataUser1 = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('contentUser1');
  if(dataUser1==null){dataUser1=''};
  dataUser1+='\nSheet '  +sheet.getName()+' cell '+cell.getA1Notation()+' has been modify at '+time+' (new value = '+cell.getValue()+')';
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('contentUser1',dataUser1); 
}

function sendReport(){
  var dataUser1 = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('contentUser1');
  if(dataUser1.length >1) {
  MailApp.sendEmail('example@email.com', 'Update of Online orders ', dataUser1);
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('contentUser1','');
  } 
}
```

However, I get a "too big value" error with `dataUser1`.

I also tried to build an array to store each changed value description:

```
function grabDataTemp()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'dd-MM-yyyy')+' at '+Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),'hh:mm');;
  var changeLog =[];
  var logLength=changeLog.length; 
  if (logLength == null)
  {
    changeLog [0] ='\nSheet '  +sheet.getName()+' cell '+cell.getA1Notation()+' has been modify at '+time+' (new value = '+cell.getValue()+')';
    changeLog [1]="";
  } 
  changeLog [logLength+1] = ('\nSheet '  +sheet.getName()+' cell '+cell.getA1Notation()+' has been modify at '+time+' (new value = '+cell.getValue()+')');
  return changeLog
}

function sendReportTemp(changeLog)
{
  if(changeLog.length >1) 
  {
  MailApp.sendEmail('example@email.com', 'Update of Online orders changeLog-TRIAL ', changeLog)
  changeLog = [];
  } 
}
```

Unfortunately, it also doesn't seem to be a good solution. Can this be done somehow using an array?

Comment: Do you know what caused the error, was it someone pasting a gigantic amount of text in a cell or importing a csv or something like that?

Comment: There was quite a lot of changes recorded. The Error occurs when there was about 84 events recorded. Total number of characters 9170

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution using scriptProperties is indeed subject to limitation in the string length these properties can have.

The sheet solution should work, I'd suggest to write a script that would convert the sheets content to an html table to make it more readable.

Use one row for each change in a single column to make the code below work without any change.

code example :

```
function sendReport(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var errorMsg = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var message = '<body><div style="font-family:arial,sans;font-size:12pt"><p>Change report</p>';  
  message+= '<table style="background-color:#fafafa;border-collapse:collapse;font-family:arial,sans;font-size:9pt;" border = 1 cellpadding = 5>';
  message+='<tr valign="top" bgcolor="#FFA" cellpadding=5><th>Number</th><th>description</th></tr>';
  var c = 1;//counter
  for(var n=0;n<errorMsg.length;n++){
    message+='<tr><td align="center">'+c+'</td><td>';
    message+=errorMsg[n][0]+'</td></tr>';
    c++;
  }
  message+='</table></body>'
  var hh = 100+35*errorMsg.length;
  if(hh>500){hh=500};
  var render = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message).setWidth(940).setHeight(hh);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(render, "preview");  
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(),'change log','HTML ONLY',{'htmlBody':message})
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you exceed a quota or limitation given in [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

An option that you can do is to use [Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?csw=1) service in sending email. This service allows users to send emails with complete control over the content of the email and it's sole purpose is sending email.

Try going through the documentation for a more detailed information on the available methods and for sample codes that you can try.

In addition to that, you may also check [G Suite email sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852). It might also help.